Reshaping out tensor in pytorch produces weird behavior
I was going through https://github.com/parrt/fundamentals-of-deep-learning/blob/main/notebooks/3.train-test-diabetes.ipynb as an exercise, but forgot to reshape y tensors in these lines
y_train = torch.tensor(y_train).float().reshape(-1,1) # column vector
y_test = torch.tensor(y_test).float().reshape(-1,1)

And my model just stopped learning early on, loss was not improving in training. Does anyone understand what's the effect of those reshape() calls, how do I avoid this bug in the future?
Full code and comments below:
def train1(model, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test,
           learning_rate = .5, nepochs=2000):
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
    history = [] # track training and validation loss
    for epoch in range(nepochs+1):
        y_pred = model(X_train)
        loss = torch.mean((y_pred - y_train)**2)
        y_pred_test = model(X_test)
        loss_test = torch.mean((y_pred_test - y_test)**2)
        history.append((loss, loss_test))
        if epoch % (nepochs//10) == 0:
            print(f"Epoch {epoch:4d} MSE train loss {loss:12.3f}   test loss {loss_test:12.3f}")
            
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward() # autograd computes w1.grad, b1.grad, ...
        optimizer.step()
    return torch.tensor(history)


ncols = X_train.shape[1]
n_neurons = 150
model2 = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(ncols, n_neurons),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(n_neurons, 1)
)

d = load_diabetes()
df = pd.DataFrame(d.data, columns=d.feature_names)
df['disease'] = d.target # "quantitative measure of disease progression one year after baseline"
print (df.head(3))


np.random.seed(1) # set a random seed for consistency across runs
n = len(df)
X = df.drop('disease',axis=1).values
y = df['disease'].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20) 


m = np.mean(X_train,axis=0)
std = np.std(X_train,axis=0)
X_train = (X_train-m)/std
X_test = (X_test-m)/std      


X_train = torch.tensor(X_train).float()
X_test = torch.tensor(X_test).float()

# HERE !!!!!!
# without reshape: train loss doesn't emprove beyond epoch 800, loss=6074 
# y_train = torch.tensor(y_train).float()
# y_test = torch.tensor(y_test).float()
# print (y_train.shape, y_test.shape) # torch.Size([353]) torch.Size([89])

# with reshape, train loss goes down to 7
y_train = torch.tensor(y_train).float().reshape(-1,1) # column vector
y_test = torch.tensor(y_test).float().reshape(-1,1)
print (y_train.shape, y_test.shape) # torch.Size([353]) torch.Size([89])

########################################################################




history = train1(model2, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test,
                 learning_rate=.02, nepochs=8000)

# Epoch    0 MSE train loss    29603.037   test loss    26998.922
# Epoch  800 MSE train loss     2133.840   test loss     3174.325
# Epoch 1600 MSE train loss     1423.420   test loss     4316.454
# Epoch 2400 MSE train loss      375.720   test loss     7257.883
# Epoch 3200 MSE train loss      120.477   test loss     9051.368
# Epoch 4000 MSE train loss       57.527   test loss    10240.634
# Epoch 4800 MSE train loss       31.486   test loss    10784.966
# Epoch 5600 MSE train loss       16.044   test loss    11113.780
# Epoch 6400 MSE train loss        8.490   test loss    11283.872
# Epoch 7200 MSE train loss        6.594   test loss    11503.454
# Epoch 8000 MSE train loss        3.513   test loss    11644.484


Assume you don't reshape. Your model outputs y_pred of size (batch_size, 1). Your y tensor is shape (batch_size,) - missing the unit axis. The axis difference causes the y tensor to be broadcast along y_pred, which is wrong. When you compute (y_pred - y), you get a tensor of shape (batch_size, batch_size), comparing every y value to every y_pred value.
When you reshape, you get a y tensor with shape (batch_size, 1). This results in the correct loss computation where (y_pred - y) has shape (batch_size, 1).
ncols = 8
n_neurons = 150
model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(ncols, n_neurons),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(n_neurons, 1) # model outputs tensor of shape `(batch_size, 1)`
)

batch_size = 64
x = torch.randn(batch_size, ncols)
y = torch.randn(batch_size) # y is shape `(batch_size)`

y_pred = model(x)
print(y.shape, y_pred.shape) # pred and target different shapes
# > torch.Size([64]) torch.Size([64, 1])

loss = (y_pred - y).pow(2)
print(loss.shape) # this causes the loss to broadcast
# > torch.Size([64, 64])

y_reshaped = y.reshape(-1, 1)
print(y_reshaped.shape) # when you reshape the axes match
# > torch.Size([64, 1])

loss = (y_pred - y_reshaped).pow(2)
print(loss.shape) # we get the correct loss shape
# > torch.Size([64, 1])

